# Embedded build status in Jenkins(localhost link)

Tags: jenkins, intellij-idea, localhost, markdown

I am using [Embeddable Build Status Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Embeddable+Build+Status+Plugin) for Jenkins and gettting following links to build status badge:

**Markdown (with view)**

```
protected
[![Build Status](http://localhost:8080/job/Spider/badge/icon)](http://localhost:8080/job/Spider/)

unprotected
[![Build Status](http://localhost:8080/buildStatus/icon?job=Spider)](http://localhost:8080/job/Spider/)
```

---

Link to the badge is working fine:

[image: badge]

But when I add it to my `README.md` file it is not showing the image. So far I have tried the following(first two images are local images to test, if images are generally working in my `README.md`):

```
![image info](file:///C://Users/Rtv24/Desktop/flower.png)

![image info](file:///C:\Users\Rtv24\Desktop\flower.png)

![alt text](localhost:8080/job/Spider/)

[![Build Status](localhost:8080/buildStatus/icon?job=Spider)](localhost:8080/job/Spider/)

[![Build Status](http://localhost:8080/buildStatus/icon?job=Spider)](http://localhost:8080/job/Spider/)
```

and as the result I am getting this:

[image: result]

---

As you can see, first two(local) images are working, but links to the build status not.

Is it possible to add this feature with link to `localhost`? If yes, how?

***PS*** My Jenkins is running on `localhost`, so that's why I am getting such kind of link to build status badge.

Comment: It works only for direct links to .png/.svg files: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-17292. Feel free to create separate request to resolve your kind of links.